# Not able to add class using .addClass() method for checkbox in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, class, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4's form validation classes for the effect.

If on submit form validation fail, I add Bootstrap class `is-invalid` to not validated elements (in the specific case a checkbox). The same code works perfectly in some cases but not in other. When it doesn't work i noted that if I `console.log(element)` the element has `is-invalid` class but if I inspect HTML code there isn't `is-invalid` in element classes...

This is a code extraction...

```
<?php $random_id = mt_rand( 1000, 9999 ); $gdpr_checkbox_id = "gdpr_checkbox_$random_id"; ?>

<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
<div class="form-group text-justify px-1">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="<?=$gdpr_checkbox_id?>" name="gdpr_checkbox" required>
        <span class="custom-control-label font-italic" for="ccwhatsapp_gdpr_checkbox" style="font-size: smaller;">GDPR disclaimer</span>
        <span class="invalid-feedback font-weight-bolder">Invalid feedback</span>
    </label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'form.needs-validation' ).on( 'submit', function( event ) {
        if ( this.checkValidity() === false ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            let checkbox = $( '#ccwhatsapp_gdpr_checkbox_' + get_id_number( $( event.delegateTarget ) ) ); //it's the right checkbox

            console.log(checkbox); //Object { 0: input#gdpr_checkbox_XXXX.custom-control-input, length: 1, [...] }
            checkbox.addClass( 'is-invalid' );
            console.log(checkbox); //Object { 0: input#gdpr_checkbox_XXXX.custom-control-input.is-invalid, length: 1, [...] } but if I inspect HTML there is not is-invalid class...
        }
    } );
} )
```

[I make a short video on YouTube to show what happens...](https://youtu.be/s2T6VLW-2hI)

Comment: well most likely because let checkbox is null. what does the function get_id_number looks like

Comment: change `#ccwhatsapp_gdpr_checkbox_(randomId)` with `#gdpr_checkbox_(randomId)`

Comment: `get_id_number()` is a function that I wrote to obtain a random number that I associate to elements id's. The checkbox is not null, I check with `console.log()`, read comments, please!

Comment: @icolumbro Do you have multiple checkboxes or the form is exactly given in your question ?

Comment: @Gulshan it's just a typo, trust me, in original full code there aren't syntax errors...

Comment: @Ajith in the form where `is-valid` class doesn't work there is just one checkbox like in the example...

Comment: Try https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation for form validation

Comment: @icolumbro as I tried here. By changing this `typo`, its working good

Comment: @Gulshan I kown jQuery Validation plugin but for my purposes in this case Bootstrap 4 validation is enough for me...

I used in similar code and it works, the problem is in the checkbox HTML it's not added the `is-invalid` class, jQuery/JavaScript add the class only in the DOM element, why?!?

Comment: @icolumbro as I mentioned in the previous comment. did you try after that typo change?

Comment: @icolumbro can you post `get_id_number()` function here

Comment: @icolumbro check my updated answer. There was an issue with `$(event.delegateTarget )` function

Comment: Hey guys, thank you all but I tried to rewrite my own code in a "blank context" instead of WordPress plugin I'm developing and in that "blank context" it works...
I don't know why in the "WordPress plugin context" the `is-invalid` class is not added to HTML element. I'm sure 100% the problem is that because (excuse repetition) I if inspect HTML source and I add `is-invalid` class to checkbox manually there aren't problems... I can't understand...

Comment: I added a link to a YouTube video where I try to show what happens...